# How to build AOSP app?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build the Camera App from AOSP.

I am on UBUNTU 14.04.

I followed the guide in the official documentation. At the end I execute

```
make Camera
```

I get the following error.

```
...
...
including ./system/media/audio_utils/Android.mk ...
including ./system/media/camera/src/Android.mk ...
including ./system/media/camera/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./system/netd/client/Android.mk ...
including ./system/netd/server/Android.mk ...
including ./system/security/keystore-engine/Android.mk ...
including ./system/security/keystore/Android.mk ...
including ./system/security/softkeymaster/Android.mk ...
including ./system/vold/Android.mk ...
including ./tools/external/fat32lib/Android.mk ...
make: *** No rule to make target `Camera'.  Stop.
#### make failed to build some targets (33 seconds) ####
```

1)How can I build a specific app from AOSP source and where does the output located? What is the format of output? Is it possible to produce an .apk file?

2)Is it possible to edit the source in Android Studio and compile it? I know that the official AOSP page contains some resources about eclipse already.

Comment: Why not just pull the code from the Camera app and implement it in your own app.

Comment: That might work, but apps that are within AOSP often tend to use various bits of non-SDK functionality, meaning that code pulled out can require changes (sometimes to an extreme extent, other times trivially) before it will build against the SDK.  I don't know if that is the case for the Camera app in question though.

Comment: Which Android branch or release are you trying to build? Do you have the packages/apps/Camera directory in your source workspace?

Comment: I am on the master branch. I have download the whole AOSP. I have the /packages/apps/Camera

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first need to set up your build environment by calling:

```
##> source build/envsetup.sh
##> launche <your-device-config>
```

Only then, call the make command to build the Camera:

```
make Camera -j8
```

your device should be one of the device configurations, for example "hammerhead" is for Nexus5

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 camera apps. The old version is called LegacyCamera and the newer version Camera2.
You don't need to run make in order to compile them. You can just run

'mmm packages/apps/Camera2'

OR

'mmm packages/apps/LegacyCamera'

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt', needed by `out/target/common/obj/APPS/Camera2_intermediates/src/R.stamp'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/media/giorgos/4d21ffd4-42ff-4237-905a-ce95b528d7a5/home/giorgos/AOSP'

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####

Comment: How about compuling it all and taking the apk you need from the out directory?

Comment: The build can take hours. I don't it produces apk files. I think the output is an image file

Comment: It may take about 2-3 hours depending on your hardware and assuming you use make -j8 (8 parallel jobs). It does create an image file, but also the apk files for all apps

Answer (score 0):

'make camera2' will build all the dependencies and then the actual camera2 app, which will be placed somewhere in out/, depending on your selected lunch target.

Once you've built it once to get the dependencies, mmm packages/apps/Camera2 will be a fast incremental compile, but it doesn't on its own build the dependencies.