# Build android app with AOSP

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

I'm trying to build an app that extends TrustAgentService, which isn't in the public SDK. I have an existing Android Studio gradle app that I need to enhance so.
I've downloaded the AOSP code (7.1.1 for Pixel, builds successfully), and created a Android Studio project using `development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh`, and following [this](https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html) guide

The AS project has a lot of unresolved symbols, and when I try to build it, it complains about

> Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'android'
>   Error:Android Source Generator: [android] Android SDK is not specified

How, if possible, can I build the exisiting gradle app against the AOSP?

If this isn't possible, how can I overcome the errors when trying to import the AOSP to Android Studio (2.3.3)?

Comment: is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736503/how-to-build-aosp-app?

Comment: if no, have you find a solution to easily test your system app? (without need for compile entire AOSP and burn it on device each time)